# How do you tell CMake to statically link to a library in a package found with find_package?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I am building a library from source and an executable that depends on the library. The library depends on a third-party library, `libjpeg`, which I would like to handle via static linking. `libjpeg` is installed on my system. I can see the `.a` file at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a`(I am building on Ubuntu.)

When processing my library's `CMakeLists.txt` file, CMake successfully finds `libjpeg` but its output announces that is has found the dynamic version of libjpeg i.e. the output from CMake is

> ```
> -- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (found version "80")
> ```

then later in the `CMakeLists.txt` I link my library to `libjpeg` via

```
target_link_libraries( my_library
    PRIVATE JPEG
)
```

and building is succesful. However when I then link to my_library from my_executable I get the following error:

> ```
> [100%] Linking CXX executable my_executable
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lJPEG
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

which I take to mean that the problem is that since `my_library` is linking to `libjpeg` dynamically I would need to `target_link_libraries` to `libjpeg` from the executable rather than the library. In any case what I want to do is completely hide `my_library`'s dependency on `libjpeg`.

Is there some way to tell `find_package` to prefer static libraries?

Comment: `target_link_libraries(my_library PRIVATE JPEG::JPEG)` — that does not answer the question, but that will make the dynamic linking work. So at least you don't start your problem solving from a broken state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything, you should fix your script:

```
target_link_libraries(my_library PRIVATE JPEG::JPEG)
```

You have to give the imported target name to `target_link_libraries`.

That being said, no, not directly. `find_package` itself does nothing of the sort, it simply looks for the correct script and calls it. Thus the actual behavior is library-specific. For libjpeg, probably it finds a copy of [this script](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/FindJPEG.cmake) and runs it.

For libjpeg in particular, `FindJPEG.cmake` provides no way to tell it to prefer static or dynamic version.

However, you can define JPEG_LIBRARY_RELEASE before calling find_package, to force it to find a specific version. For instance, if you do:

```
cmake -DJPEG_LIBRARY_RELEASE=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a .....
```

Then you should get a static build (replace with `JPEG_LIBRARY_DEBUG` to define the debug version). You can do the same with pretty much any detected thing where you want to force the detection of something else, as most script will not overwrite values defined on the command line.

If that suits your workflow, perfect. Otherwise, you won't have a clean solution with CMake alone, and you should add a dependency manager on top of that (vcpkg, conan.io).

Comment: How should I have known what the imported target name was? How do packages found by `find_package` get names?

Comment: The script found and run by find_package will create imported targets (if modern enough and well designed). So it's package-specific too. For libjpeg, it is documented there: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJPEG.html#imported-targets Granted, if you are not familiar with cmake, it is not that obvious that the useful bit is the imported targets section.

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate the name:

```
find_library(JPEGLIB REQUIRED NAMES libjpeg.a)
add_executable(myapp myapp.c)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE ${JPEGLIB})
```

> Each library name given to the NAMES option is first considered as a library file name and then considered with platform-specific prefixes (e.g. lib) and suffixes (e.g. .so). Therefore one may specify library file names such as libfoo.a directly. This can be used to locate static libraries on UNIX-like systems.

Comment: Note that if you do away with the find_package, you also have to locate the headers and `target_include_directories` them. And this will only work on systems where the library is actually named `libjpeg.a`, so if you want to support other systems / distros you need to add all the possible names. You also should set `IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_<CONFIG>` to C in some way to ensure linking is done correctly for a C++ application. Or in short, you have to reimplement FindJPEG.cmake.